# Required changes to migrate to Kubernetes 1.16

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I have a multi-component platform which I created the required helm charts for it and it was properly working on Kubernetes <= 1.15.

Now I need to prepare them to be compatible with k8s 1.16. I thought that it is just enough to change the `extensions/v1beta1` to `apps/v1` but after I tried to install the helm charts on k8s I got this error:

```
Error: release test166 failed: Deployment.apps "bridge-http" is invalid: [spec.selector: Required value, spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"io.kompose.service":"bridge-http"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`]
```

And this is my yaml/helm file which works on older k8s:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    Process: bridge-http
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: bridge-http
  name: bridge-http
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "9995"
    port: 9995
    targetPort: 9995
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: bridge-http
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
# apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    Process: bridge-http
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: bridge-http
  name: bridge-http
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: bridge-http
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - bash
        - -c
        - npm start
        env:
        - name: WWS_BRIDGE_HTTP_BROKER_DATA_USER
          value: {{ .Values.WWS_BRIDGE_HTTP_BROKER_DATA_USER | quote }}
        image: {{ .Values.image }}
        name: bridge-http
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 9995
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 15
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9995
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.1
            memory: 250Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 5Gi
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: wwssecret
status: {}
```

I couldn't find anything regarding changes in selectors and lables here: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/

So why I am getting this error and how I can solve it?

Comment: you need in the deployment selector.matchLabels tells us how the deployment finds which pods it should be managing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of the 1.16 upgrade we have changed extensions/v1beta1 to apps/v1. Along with this you need to add below snippet under main spec.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    Process: bridge-http
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: bridge-http
  name: bridge-http
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: bridge-http  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bridge-http
```

Comment: the select need to be on io.kompose.service label.

Comment: @AVarf to have a valid example, you can use this command "kubectl run --image=nginx nginx-app --dry-run -o yaml"